# 500 Internal Error when trying to commit anything to a migrated Visual SVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have followed the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609065/migrating-visual-svn-server-from-one-windows-install-to-another) to move my Visual SVN Server from one Window box to another and everything appeared ok, my repos, users and groups appeared in my new Server Manager.

I can check out the repos fine, but if I try to commit any changes I get a 500 Internal Error. I've tried TortoiseSVN but if I try using the Visual Studio Ankh plug-in I get a little more detail as follows:

> SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: Commit failed (details follow):
>   ---> SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: POST of '/svn/stuff/!svn/me': 500 Internal Server Error (https://stuffserver.com:8443)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client,
>   SvnException error, Object targets)    at
>   SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client,
>   svn_error_t* error, Object targets)    at
>   SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args,
>   SvnCommitResult& result)    at
>   Ankh.Services.PendingChanges.PendingChangeHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1b.b__19(Object
>   sender, ProgressWorkerArgs e)    at
>   Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)

I get the same behaviour if I create a new repo on the server and try to commit to it so I suspect there's a problem that's been introduced by copying the folder over? My VisualSVN Server version is v2.5.1, an old version I know, but this is the same as the source server version and I wanted to do the migration first before I got into any form of upgrade.

Comment: Commin from command line, show full output... and add content of SVN-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by copying the repos folder *after* installing Visual SVN Server on my new server. It looks like the way Visual SVN Server manages permissions on that folder was being broken when that folder was overwritten.

If you copy the repos folder to the new server first, then install Visual SVN Server and point it to the repos folder when the installer asks you, you will see "Adjusting permissions" during the installation.

Everything worked from then on for me.

Comment: You can also adjust permissions by going to **VisualSVN Server Manager | Action | Properties | Storage** and checking *Automatically adjust permissions*.

Comment: That was already checked for me, unchecking and rechecking that didn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error is:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
POST of '/svn/stuff/!svn/me': 500 Internal Server Error
```

You can [check VisualSVN Server's log](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/) to see why you get the error on client.