# VisualSVN Server - Moving a very old repository to a new installation that is several versions newer and on a new Windows OS

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

We have a repository on a Windows Server 2003 machine (32-bit) that is running VisualSVN Server v2.1.1 (circa 2010).  We are in the process of setting up a Windows Server 2012 machine (64-bit) and preparing to migrate that repository.  We'll be installing the latest version of VisualSVN Server and would like to make the transition as smooth as possible.

I have found information on upgrading versions when staying on the same machine (https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00116/).  And have also found information on moving from one installation to another ([Migrating Visual SVN Server from one Windows install to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609065/migrating-visual-svn-server-from-one-windows-install-to-another?newreg=379c26fb26de494a908210a4563326ea))

I have not found anything on doing both at the same time.  The last version that supports Windows Server 2003 is v2.7.14 so I figure that is as far as I can go in upgrades on the existing installation.  I am concerned about losing the file history and associated revision notes and want to do anything I can to preserve them.

Does anyone have experience with moving a repository to a new OS and jumping several versions at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps specified in the article [KB166: Migrating VisualSVN Server to another computer](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00166/).

> Does anyone have experience with moving a repository to a new OS and
>   jumping several versions at the same time?

You need to install your current VisualSVN Server version on the new computer. Configure it, move your repositories. Upgrade to a newer VisualSVN Server version when all is done.